# No network access when debugging on Droid X

Tags: android

I just picked up a used Droid X for development and when I try to debug from eclipse I don't have any network access. Works fine when I run the app non-debug. I've installed the Moto USB drivers for Windows and I've tried all the USB connection types on the phone and before you ask, yes USB debugging is turned on. I can step through the code and such, just no network access.

Anyone else see this problem? Any solution?

Comment: Just tried it on my Macbook Pro too and same issue there.

Comment: By network, do you mean wi-fi network or the cellphone network ? Are any signal bars showing ?

Comment: The phone is Verizon but not activated, so wifi. wifi is on and works fine except when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just figured it out. If I put the phone in airplane mode but leave wifi on it works. Guess when I'm debugging it's ignoring wifi and looking for 3g which it can't find because the phone isn't activated.

Thanks sandyiscool for making me think of trying that :)

Comment: Actually it's still flakey. Seems to be intermittent when connecting via ssl for some reason (https vs http).

Comment: Turns out it was the SSL Library I was using. I just turn off ssl for debugging now and it works.